# I disabled Hyper-V with Bluestacks 5 emulator, Now I cant use it even after turning it on

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

I downloaded the latest Bluestacks v5. 
It prompted me to turn Hyper-V off, and it gave a official support link.
 I downloaded the HD-DisableHyperV_native_v2.exe (custom exe file to disable hyper-v by bluestacks) and ran it. 
[Link: https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055244412-How-to-disable-Hyper-V-on-Windows-for-BlueStacks-5#%E2%80%9C3%E2%80%9D] 
 It disabled Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Subsystem for Linux.
 Now I found that Windows Subsystem for Android was in beta, so I installed it. 
 I tried opening files app on it, but its shows to enable "Virtual Machine Platform" even after I enabled it on the control panel.
 Not only that, but Oracle Virtual Box also shows the same. 
 Please help me with this problem.
 Edit: I tried uninstalling BlueStacks. It didn't help me in this problem anyways.

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, rollback to before you disabled Hyper-V.

Comment: Have you uninstalled Bluestacks?

Comment: I tried uninstalling it also. it didn't help at anyways.

Comment: I didn't enable System Restore

Comment: That exactly happened to me after installing HD-DisableHyperV_native_v2.exe, Docker stopped working. I think that what we are looking for here is to REVERT what was done by HD-DisableHyperV_native_v2.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. One of these fixed it. I'm not sure which. I rebooted after doing all of these in a powershell with admin rights

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

BCDEDIT /Set `{current`} hypervisorlaunchtype auto

DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: The you should mark the answer as correct @UnityGameDev99999

Comment: I tried one by one, to acknowledge which is the solution. And the second one was the correct fix. I didn't even test the 3rd. I reeboted my PC on each try. So basically we can conclude that what HD-DisableHyperV_native_v2.exe does is to set the value of hypervisorlaunchtype to off.